# Why can't we write the entire 24 volumes of the Encyclopedia Britannica on the head of a pin?

Tags: nanoscience

In his 1959 talk titled [There's Plenty of Room at the Bottom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_Plenty_of_Room_at_the_Bottom) Feynmann discussed the miniaturisation of information storage and as part of this proposed that the entire contents of the Encyclopaedia Brittanica could be written on a pin head. [A PDF of the talk is available here](http://calteches.library.caltech.edu/47/2/1960Bottom.pdf).

However I don't think we can input their information on $1 mm^2$. Is it impossible to create many information on $1 mm^2$ in real? Actually now there isn't such a thing after 50 years later. If it's possible, please tell me that mechanism.

Comment: Why don't you think it's possible? Doesn't the talk explain why?

Comment: 1mm^2 is 10^-6 meters^2 . (10 nanometers )^2  are 10^-16 meters square.  http://www.nanowerk.com/nanotechnology/introduction/introduction_to_nanotechnology_31.php

Comment: I don't care even if 1nm^2, 1mm^2, or 1cm^2.

Comment: I guess the only limitation is that you would have troubles procuring funding for a special AFM system with sufficient spatial extent, reliability and durability. You would also have to keep the encyclopedia in vacuum to prevent its gradual deterioration.

Comment: I found DNA storage is good example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_digital_data_storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [DNA strand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA) has a diameter of about $2\times 10^{-9}\,\mathrm{m}$, and let's assume we can encode a bit in a length of $2\times 10^{-9}\,\mathrm{m}$ of DNA.  Further assume we can lay DNA strands next to each other with no space between them.

With these assumptions a bit requires $4\times 10^{-18}\,\mathrm{m}^2$.  The area of a pinhead is approximately $10^{-6}\,\mathrm{m}^2$, so you can fit about $2.5\times 10^{11}$ bits on a pinhead this way.

The Encyclopaedia Britannica seems to fit on a DVD (at least you can buy it on a DVD according to Wikipedia).  The biggest DVDs ([DVD-18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD)) seem to be about $16\times 2^{30}$ bytes, which is about $1.7\times 10^{11}$ bytes or about $1.4\times 10^{12}$ bits.

So, encoding data like this we are short by a factor of about ten.  However I have been fairly pessimistic about the encoding density of DNA: a nucleotide, which is two bits, seems to take only about $3.3\times 10^{-10}\,\mathrm{m}$ in fact (see above reference).  Also I have overestimated the size of the Encyclopedia Britannica: according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica), the last printed edition was $32,640$ pages, which, assuming $100$ lines of $100$ characters per page (an overestimate), one byte per character (a slight underestimate perhaps), is about $2.6\times 10^9$ bits, which will fit easily even including illustrations.

I have ignored compressibility of the data and the need for redundancy in the representation: assume they cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

So, in 1959, Feynman calculated that you need to decrease the area of the pages of Britannica 25000 times to fit their content on the surface of a pin head. He offered a prize of $1000 for recording a page of a book on a surface 25000 smaller than that of the page. Some 25 years later the prize was claimed using electron beam lithography (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Newman_(scientist) ,http://archives.caltech.edu/news/feynman-nanotech.html)

Comment: I saw the site 30 minutes ago.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki so you saw it... and what? Does it invalidate the answer?

Comment: Obviously invalid answer. So I ask the mechanism, too.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki : I mentioned the mechanism - the electron beam lithography (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron-beam_lithography)

Comment: @akhmeteli With one line explanation?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: Answers don't have to be perfect. Did I have to copy-paste the Wikipedia article or some other source? "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful" (http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @akhmeteli I don't call the comment pasted a article of wikipedia answer. There is no discussion about Electron-beam lithography in your answer. Also, the first sentence of your answer is quite obvious.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: Look, I mentioned the mechanism in my answer. You could look up the mechanism yourself. According to community manager (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), "See, this is an answer: "You probably want FileOutputStream" ...Yes, they're both very short, and yes, they contain links. But strip the markup, and you still get at least a little bit of useful information. " If you don't like my answer, I'm fine with that, but when you say that my answer is invalid, I respectfully disagree.